# How do I run wireshark, with root-privileges?

Tags: permissions, wireshark

A standard installation of Wireshark doesn't give the program permission to access the network interface.

I suppose I have to run the program with `sudo`, but do not know how to add it to the icon - if that's the way to do it.

Comment: Are you talking about WireShark? If not, can you link to the application's home page so we can see what you're talking about. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, he's probably talking about [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) rather than WireShark. :-)

Comment: You could try `tcpdump` tool in Linux if `wireshark` is giving you too much troubles.

Comment: For me its OK to run: First: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common`select yes then: `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap`

Answer (score 182, accepted):

For WireShark there's a better way. The bit that normally needs root is the packet collection application and this can be configured to allow certain people to use it without `sudo`, `gksu`, `etc`.

In a terminal (very important that you're in a terminal, not just the Alt+F2 dialogue) run this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

This will ask you if you want to allow non-root user to be able to sniff. That's what we're aiming for, so select `Yes` and hit return.

[image: Reconfiguring wireshark-common]

This adds a `wireshark` group. Anybody in that group will be able to sniff without being root. This is obviously more secure than just letting *anybody* sniff but does mean there's no password checking. Technically any person with access to a computer logged in with a `wireshark` account will be able to sniff. If that's acceptable to you, carry on.

If not, run that again and select no.

Then you just need to add the user to that group. Run this:

```
sudo adduser $USER wireshark
```

And restart or log out. When you're back in it should let you start sniffing without any fuss about being root.

Comment: Any way to skip restart/logout step?

Comment: This solution stopped working in 14.04

Comment: @Janghou Still works for me. Did add your user to the wireshark group and restart?

Comment: @Oli, I upgraded from 13.10 and it stopped working. I tried now again and after a restart it worked (with some hassle). Thx.

Comment: And, yes, it's definitely a *much* better way than running Wireshark as root.  The README.packaging file in the Wireshark source says "WIRESHARK CONTAINS OVER TWO MILLION LINES OF SOURCE CODE. DO NOT RUN THEM AS ROOT."

Comment: @TahaJahangir no, groups are applied on login, so you need to re-login for group changes to take effect.

Comment: +1 for info about `adduser` for wireshark.

Comment: @TahaJahangir If restart/logout is inconvenient, you can use the `newgrp wireshark` command to temporarily enter the group after you have become a member of the `wireshark` group.

Comment: @TahaJahangir and Oli: Much more convenient than logging out is to use `su - $USER` as described at [Reload a Linux user's group assignments without logging out - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out)

Comment: @TahaJahngir & Lekensleyn -- The `newgp` command changes your primary group id.  That denied me access to key mounted filesystems.  Much more reliable to use `su - username`.

Comment: It just bothers me that this dialog window says both "This is recommended" and "this may be a security risk ... it is suggested to leave it disabled". The conflicting statements are confusing, and even had me wondering if the "it" that it's referring to in both sentences are one and the same.

Answer (score 13):

Really you do not need to launch WireShark as root. Please read [official page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges). In brief you should do:

```
sudo groupadd wireshark
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
sudo chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo chmod o-rx /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

Then log-out and log-in again.

Note: this method was tested on 16.04 LTS, 17.10 and 18.04 LTS.

Comment: This will remain interfaces from loading unless changed.
sudo chgrp USER_NAME /usr/bin/dumpcap

Comment: problem: chgrp:  invalid group: 'o-rx'

Answer (score 4):

You can also run Wireshark with root privileges by running `gksu wireshark` from the terminal.

Note that there are security concerns with running Wireshark in this mode, namely that any exploit that compromises Wireshark now has root privileges rather than user privileges. This is more of a concern with Wireshark than other application because, by it's very nature (capturing and processing arbitrary input), Wireshark is more vulnerable to exploits than typical desktop applications. You are probably safe on a SOHO network, but you should be aware of this concern before proceeding.

**Citations:**

- [Capture privileges: Most UNIXes](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges#Most_UNIXes)
- [Security](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Security) including:

  - [Why is Wireshark so buggy?](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Security#Why_is_Wireshark_so_buggy.3F)
  - [Administrator/root account not required!](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Security#Administrator.2Froot_account_not_required.21)
- [Debian README](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/collab-maint/ext-maint/wireshark/trunk/debian/README.Debian?view=markup) (also applies to Ubuntu)

Comment: I just configured it with --enable-setcap-install flag then I can't do this.

Comment: This is far more dangerous and more problematic, because there are for more exploitable bugs when running the full gui as root, and configuration issues can crop up when a gui program runs as root.  See the dpkg-reconfigure solution above for a much better option.

Comment: For desktop users, I consider this to be a workaround. When you sudo the app, all files it creates have root permission, and you need to constantly keep changing file permissions to make them available to your current user in your home directory. For server and sysadmins in general, sudo is actually the best approach.

Comment: @JulioHM Running Wireshark as root is dangerous for everyone, including server and sysadmins.

Comment: At approximately line 40 of [Wireshark's doc/README.packaging file](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.packaging;hb=HEAD), it says "WIRESHARK CONTAINS OVER TWO MILLION LINES OF SOURCE CODE. DO NOT RUN THEM AS ROOT."  Take that statement very seriously.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this also, open the terminal, run this command

```
# setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

run wireshark as a non-root user