# Wireshark problem. Can't select default interface

Tags: 11.10, networking, interface

I downloaded `Wireshark` from the Ubuntu 11.10 software center and when I start it and want to select default interface for capture in the list of interfaces are blank. I can't select default interface. Please help me.

Comment: Try running wireshark by `gksudo wireshark`, you will need *sudo* permissions to capture packets on your network interface.

Comment: The answers here are more dangerous than the standard "sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common" approach, which is documented in this question: [How do I run WireShark, with root-privileges? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges).  This question is essentially a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run wireshark with sudo priveleges - `gksudo wireshark`. You will need super-user permission to capture packets from your network interface.

Comment: No problem :) Most welcome :)

Comment: This is unnecessarily dangerous and problematic, because there are far more exploitable bugs when running the full gui as root, and configuration issues can crop up when a gui program runs as root. See the dpkg-reconfigure solution at [How do I run WireShark, with root-privileges? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges) for a much better option

Comment: I just saw that and have also voted to close this question off as a duplicate of that one. Thanks for pointing this out @nealmcb :)

Answer (score 1):

This command string worked in my case. I don't run anything as root if I don't have to.

```
sudo chgrp your username /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

Comment: Super helpful because this relates to anything using libpcap, not just dumpcap + wireshark. Got me out of a pinch, thanks!