# Setting up wireshark for non root user

Tags: permissions, wireshark

I am setting up wireshark to run as non root user, a la [here](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/7976/wireshark-setup-linux-for-nonroot-user), that is:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common 
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
(restart)
```

This is all great. But when I try to start wireshark as the wireshark user, using:

```
sudo -s -u $USER wireshark
```

I get the following error:

```
no protocol specified
gtk-warning ** cannot open display
```

The "no protocol specified" part seems pretty straight forward. And the gtk-warning cannot open display seems to relate exactly to this [issue](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200712/msg00102.html).

> "You have two ways to get this working: grant it or have root take it.
>   You (greg) can grant it by means of 'xhost local:root'. Or root can take it, because it can access your files:
>   'export AUTHORITY=/home/greg/.Xauthority'."

This doesn't make sense to me. What was the point in granting access to the other user if they can't open the program anyway? This separating is done for security reasons, so isn't making that above modification reverting the earlier comment

> "This has to do with access control to your X server. You don't want just anybody opening windows on your screen, do you. So if you started the X server under your own account (greg) then any other user (like root) doesn't have access to it."

TLDR; Is this standard practice and the way this should be done, to achieve separation between root and other user account? It seems like a "hack" to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run wireshark, with root-privileges?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges)

Answer (score 12):

`$USER` is here to see as a shell variable. The third command above adds your user to the `wireshark group` and should be replaced by `sudo adduser <yourUser> wireshark`.
Now you should be able to invoke wireshark **as yourself** (no need to sudo anymore).

As has been pointed out by Guerlando Ocs you **may** encounter a situation where the group *wireshark* doesn't exist. In this case you can resolve the problem by first running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

and selecting *yes* so it creates the group for non root users.

Comment: If there's no `wireshark` group as in my case, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common` and select yes so it creates the group for non root users

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs thank you for the observation and solution! I edited it into the answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I installed Wireshark and made it work, running it as non-root user:

Install Wireshark:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dreibh/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Enable it to run as non-root user:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
sudo adduser <yourUser> wireshark
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

Comment: Why do you suggest to use a ppa? Wireshark is available in the standard repository.

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap` did the trick

Comment: Attention people: NEVER install things from random ppas from the internet. It's just a repository compiled by anyone. And this is very dangerous

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap` can be avoided by restarting the system after adding the user to the `wireshark` group.

Answer (score 0):

Install Wireshark

There are mainly two PPA provided By Wireshark Developer team 1. Stable release 2. Nightly Release ( Link to [Wireshark Developers official stable/Nightly PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wireshark-dev) )

1. Using Wireshark Developers Stable release (Up to Ubuntu Bionic)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable -y
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install wireshark
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
   sudo adduser $USER wireshark
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap
   ```
2. Using Wireshark Developers Nightly Release (supported upto ubuntu xenial)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/nightly
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install wireshark
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
   sudo adduser $USER wireshark
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dumpcap
   ```

Don't forget logout the current user and re-login ( adding user group )