# wireshark problems with configuration

Tags: configuration, wireshark

I recently installed wireshark and before i could even start capturing anything it says "no interface can be used for capturing in this system with the current configuration"

as im new to wireshark, does anyone know how to change the current configuration and what to change them to?
sorry for any duplication and for shortness in description but i cant proceed without this configuration being set right

Comment: The recommended way to capture LAN packets is to re-configure it. See the answer from Oli to this question:[How do I run WireShark, with root-privileges?](http://askubuntu.com/a/74064/107450)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
The default installation of Wireshark requires root privileges to run packet capturing. This is why I suggested below to run it as a privileged user. As [@Warren Hill](https://askubuntu.com/users/107450/warren-hill) kindly pointed out this is **not the recommended way** to use Wireshark.

Please read [How do I run WireShark, with root-privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges) and follow [@Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74064/28369) on how to reconfigure Wireshark to be able to run as your own user.

To make the group membership changes effective (as stated in that answer) you'll need to log out or restart the system. If you do not want to do that right now for any reason, temporarily `login` might help. (You'll have to specify your password twice: once for `sudo` and once for `login`).

```
$ sudo login <your_user_name>
[sudo] password for <your_user_name>:
password:
$ DISPLAY=:0.0 wireshark
```

---

*Answer left below for reference:*

Try to run Wireshark with root privileges:

```
pkexec wireshark
```

According to the [Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges):

> Running Wireshark (or any other network capture/analyzer, for that
>   matter) on Linux needs root privileges. Therefore, you have to have
>   root privileges when starting Wireshark, else you can't capture data.
>   Please note that you don't have to login as root when starting your
>   computer, you can use su(1) or sudo(8) for that purpose.

Comment: ok i ran the command and it says... (wireshark:3274): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: is this normal or is there something wrong?

Comment: I've come around a workaround for this: `pkexec bash -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 wireshark"`. Could you test if Wireshark can now be started?

Comment: This is not the recommended way.  See duplicate question

Comment: @WarrenHill thanks for the heads-up! I added your advice into the answer by explaining not to do as I suggested before. While the content still remains true, I understand one should reconfigure the package instead of hacking root to be able to run it. Thanks again!

Comment: ok im kind of confused here as ive just checked the answers now. Do i type in the above command? or is that a bad thing to try?

Comment: i followed the help in the duplicate question but it says the same thing with the addition of this comment underneath "(couldn't run usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: permission denied)

Comment: I haven't found your error message in the linked question, but tried the suggested methods. Have you reconfigured `wireshark-common`? Have you added yourself to the `wireshark` group? If your answer is yes to both of these questions you have (at least) 3 options: 1) Restart Ubuntu. 2) Log out and log back in. 3) Try my temporary solution: `sudo login <your_user_name>`. All of these aim that the newly assigned group takes effect. To test if you're member of the wireshark group type `groups` in the terminal. It should list `wireshark`.

Comment: i typed groups and it did not say wireshark, when following the advice in the duplicate question it asked for the administrative password and it kept saying the password i typed was wrong when i know it wasnt??? i think this may be the problem, im not sure. Im quite new to this so im not sure if i have configured wireshark-common or even added myself to the group as im not sure how to do that! i will try restart ubuntu now but i think the problem is the administrative password, im just not sure why it says i got it wrong when its the only password i use?

Comment: Please follow Oli's answer. Each `sudo` command requires the password for your user name (it should be the same as the one you log in with). After typing in the password each command would run with root privileges. The first one reconfigures wireshark, so that anyone will be able to run it as a regular user provided (s)he is the member of the wireshark group (no root required). The second one adds you to the wireshark group. This group addition only takes effect if you logout/login. Therefore the 3 methods, but a simple restart will do.

Comment: restarting ubuntu never resolved the what could be the issue?

Comment: I think your problem might be that you could not enter your password at the `[sudo]` prompt. You should be able to do that, please try again.

Comment: in oli's answer i have ran the first command twice and selected yes for the first and no for the second time i tried, then added user as me but it states there is already a group named wireshark

Comment: Run the reconfigure command again, and select _„Yes”_. It is important, _that_ makes wireshark allow the users in the wireshark group to do the packet capture. Ignore the message about the already existing group. If you're finally able to be a member of the wireshark group, I think you'll be good to go.