# Using unity as console command launcher

Tags: unity

I wonder, is there any way to do this in Ubuntu's Unity:

- press <kbd>Super</kbd> button
- type `gksu wireshark`
- enjoy Wireshark as root

In other words: is there a way to execute shell command from unity line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much easier way to start applications the way you start them from the shell, if you don't care to open `gnome-terminal`, just type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then type

```
gksu wireshark
```

or whatever command you want to run.

<sub>**Warning:** It is not recommended to run wireshark as root, if you really want to, have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There's no lens that will act as the terminal, simply because if one wants to issue terminal commands, just typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> will open gnome-terminal.

If all you need is to launch Wireshark as root, just edit its `.desktop` file to change the way you start it, first open a terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit wireshark.desktop
```

And change the line beginning with `Exec` to add `gksudo`:

```bsh
Exec=gksudo wireshark %f
```

That way, Wireshark will always run as root is started from the unity launcher or after a query after pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.