# What is the difference between `groups $USER`and `groups` in a terminal?

Tags: command-line, user-management, wireshark

When I run the the following command in a terminal I get different output.
I try to find out if I am a member of the Wireshark group.

```
groups $USER
```

Does list wireshark

```
groups
```

Does **not** list wireshark

So do I belong to the Wireshark group or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't restarted [per the instructions on that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74064/449).

- `groups` is  shows groups *as **currently** applied* to your user
- `groups $USER` is asking the system to calculate the groups for that user.

This isn't a case of "trusting" one over the other. They show pointedly different things.

Groups are applied to a user when they log in. That's why my instructions are to restart or log out then in again. This makes the system apply the new group and thus allows you to use Wireshark.

Comment: Thx, I did log out. Tried it twice. But now after a restart it works. It actually broke after updating to 14.04. I probably forgot to add myself to the Wireshark group again, after reconfiguring sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common –

Answer (score 2):

From man `groups`:

> Print group memberships for each USERNAME or, if no USERNAME is
>   specified, for the current process (which may differ if the groups
>   database has changed).

I'd trust `groups $USER` as your current process can return different values.

Answer (score 0):

`groups` command gives current logged in users groups in which that user belongs.

& `groups username` allows to view groups in which username belongs to.

Try with your current username,

This is mine:

`username@host:~$ groups`

`username adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`

`username@host:~$ groups username`

`username : username adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`

Check with any command for whether you belong to `wireshark` or not.