# Adding an existing user to an existing group isn't working with usermod -a -G

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

I'm attempting to add myself to a group vboxshare such that my user can access a virtual box shared directory under /media. Seems easy enough.

A quick google search gives a good looking answers: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group/

```
(username: allusers)
usermod -a -G vboxsf allusers
```

Ok, did it, but no bueno, what'd I miss here? Groups have never been a fluently intuitive concept to me in linux. I do see vboxsf as a group in 2 of the 3 commands I presume to use to see what groups are assigned to me.

```
allusers@vbubuntu:/media$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 May 21 14:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root   4096 May 25 23:38 ../
drwxr-x---+  2 root root   4096 May 20 20:21 allusers/
drwxrwx---   1 root vboxsf 4096 May 31 12:20 sf_tempshare/

allusers@vbubuntu:/media$ cd sf_tempshare/
bash: cd: sf_tempshare/: Permission denied

allusers@vbubuntu:/media$ groups
allusers adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

allusers@vbubuntu:/media$ groups allusers
allusers : allusers adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxsf

allusers@vbubuntu:/media$ id allusers
uid=1000(allusers) gid=1000(allusers) groups=1000(allusers),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),999(vboxsf)
```

Comment: Default group is vboxusers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log out and then back in.

[Group changes need a fresh login to take](https://askubuntu.com/a/458828/449).

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know what to search for to find that answer. Thanks!