# How to configure Wi-Fi adaptor to monitor mode?

Tags: wireless, capture

I have just successfully installed a driver (athk9_htc) for TP-Link TL-WN722N (a USB Wi-Fi adaptor) in Ubuntu 14.04.1. My goal is to capture Wi-Fi traffic with Wireshark.

I try to configure the adaptor to monitor mode by running: `sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor`

However it gives me an error message:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06):
    SET failed on device wlan1; Device or resource busy.
```

How can I set it to monitor mode?

Edited:

I do not agree this is a duplicated question. Actually I have found that thread before I asked this question. However there are two responses in that thread, but not any verified answer. If I do not ask this question again, how can I get the answer? Also the answer given by @chili555 is different to the responses in that thread, and I verified this answer is working. If the question is duplicated, shouldn't it be added as a comment in that thread to indicate that a verified answer is here, instead of indicating an answered question is a duplicated question?

Comment: Not a duplicate at all, as it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It may work if you first bring the interface down:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
```

Check:

```
iwconfig
```

Not every device and driver combination are capable of monitor mode.

Comment: Hold on. I bring down the inferface and configure it to monitor mode. then bring it up again `sudo iwconfig wlan1 up` . It is still in monitor mode when I run `iwconfig`. However then I connect it to a WiFi hot-spot, I found that it change back to managed mode...:(

Comment: I expect so. When you connect to an AP or hotspot, you are no longer monitoring. The AP is managing the channel, bit rate, etc. The behavior you describe is altogether correct.

Comment: So I can start sniffing the WiFi with Wireshark without connecting it to an AP?

Comment: I am not experienced in wireshark, but I believe so. Please try.

Comment: Yes I have just tested it. It works.

Comment: First, you must disconnect from the AP using the network manager.  Then run the 2 commands (ifconfig and iwconfig) or else it will try to change back to monitor mode.

Comment: wait if i'm not able to connect to a ap after putting it in monitor mode, is there a way to sniff data in a wifi network? i am trying to monitor my own network

Answer (score 3):

The best way to put your Wifi adapter to monitor mode is through **airmon-ng**.

You can install it by typing into a terminal `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng`

Also, if you are using Wireshark, you have to run it as superuser to be able to put your adapter to monitor mode... :)

Comment: I read some thread that saying running Wireshark as superuser is not a good idea. In this link it suggested a way to capture without root permission [http://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges]. However it failed when I follow this method.

Comment: Without root permissions, you are not able to set your adapter to monitor mode

Comment: Lets back to the question, I still get the same error after running `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng`...

Comment: What makes you think this is the best way?

Comment: For me, today airmon-ng stopped working to go into Monitor mode for external card. Internal was going. But ifconfig/iwconfig way worked. But iwconfig way don't give me new name like wlan1mon etc. Hope this does not matter!

Answer (score 1):

Simple first make sure that you have installed drivers for your wireless adapter. Then if you want to enable monitor mode there are 2 methods to do it.

First method is by doing:

- `ifconfig wlan0 down`
- then `airmon-ng check kill`
- then type `iwconfig mode monitor` and then `ifconfig wlan0 up`
- type `service NetworkManager restart` before doing `ifconfig wlan0 up`.

Second way is by doing:

- `ifconfig wlan0 down`
- then `airmon-ng check kill`
- then type `airmon-ng start wlan0`
- then type `service NetworkManager restart` and `ifconfig up`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I disabled the network manager 1st and then able to put in monitor mode. Network manager is changing the mode back to managed mode after a while.

```
service NetworkManager stop

ifconfig wlp2s0 down
iwconfig wlp2s0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlp2s0 up
```

Comment: This works for me, but it seems to be reset after a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Wi-Fi interface is `wlp3s0`, here's how you can set it to monitor mode:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
ip link set wlp3s0 down
iw wlp3s0 set type monitor
ip link set wlp3s0 up
```

Execute the commands as root or using `sudo`.