# Follow the path of an incomming packet

Tags: networking

I want to find out why some of my routing rules are not working and where my packet takes a "wrong" turn.

Is it possible to listen to a Port ( 22 in my case ) and then follow an incomming packet ?

What is especially important for me is that I can write to a log which Route is chosen when the packet gets sent out.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start, this is a complex task and you need to have in-depth knowledge of the TCP/IP protocol so if you don't own [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469) already, buy it!

Depending on *where* the packets take a wrong turn, you will have to: (increasing number means increased difficulty)

1. Use [`gufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw)'s listening report:

   [image]

   to see whether the packets actually arrive to your machine.  This is the simplest way of seeing what's going on.
2. Use `sudo tcpdump -i interface` to have an even deeper knowledge what's happening on your machine...
3. Sniff your network using something like [`wireshark`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges) to see the packets that actually get transported on the LAN and which are never responded to.  The last one needs 2 machines: the "sniffing machine" that sniffs the network that the other machine is connected to.  Also, you need to enable a monitor port on your switch (a.k.a. "mirroring port" or "SPAN" port) or use an old-style HUB.

The last one will allow you to *follow the entire path of the packet* (which is what your question is about)

For further information, read the manuals of the respective tools otherwise you will be like [a kid trying to figure out an old-fashioned phone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkuirEweZvM)!  >:-)

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask