# usbmon errors on wireshark

Tags: permissions, wireshark

I ran `tshark` on Ubuntu/Windows 10 as follows:

```
$ tshark -i 6
Capturing on 'usbmon1'
tshark: The capture session could not be initiated on interface 'usbmon1' (Can't open USB bus file /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/1t: Permission denied). Please check to make sure you have sufficient permissions, and that you have the proper interface or pipe specified.
0 packets captured
```

**Update:**
Thank you for the advice that I got from this and the wireshark communities. I was able to handle `usbmon` as suggested and I got to to capture data for it. The way for me to run `tshark` without errors was by running it through `gksudo`.

```
gksudo -- tshark -i 1 -l -a duration:30
```

The `--` between `gksudo` and `tshark` are necessary for `tshark` to interpret the parameters. The only problem is that `^C` does not stop the running program.

Comment: gksudo tshark -i 6

Comment: gksudo tshark -i 6 does not give an error message but there is no capture, gksudo -i capture packets. So at least tshark works for me, Thanks

Comment: gksudo tshark only partially works, It appears that gksudo  does not pass the parameter list of tshark The question is how to have the entire string of options of tshark get recognized. I tried double quoting the parameter list of tshark. Used gksudo -- tshar options. That did not seem to work.

Comment: If I use gksudo tshark -i 1 -l -a duration:30,  there is no output for tshark. I tested it. On the other hand gksudo -- tshark -i 1 -l -a duration:30 leads to

Comment: If I use gksudo tshark -i 1 -l -a duration:30,  there is no output for tshark. (I tested it.) On the other hand gksudo -- tshark -i 1 -l -a duration:30 leads to normal tshark output.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: Also, this is now a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/74059/how-do-i-run-wireshark-with-root-privileges

Answer (score 1):

When I used:  `gksudo -- tshark -i 1 -l -a duration:30`, it worked without errors. What seemed to help was the -- between gksudo and tshark. 
Because I am the only user of the PC hosting Ubuntu, I am not concerned about computer safety of this approach.